# Keep object in place when AR track is found

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm pretty new with Vuforia and Unity, what I'm looking for is to have a full-screen/in place image/object (without movements) when the track is found (in keep it on screen till track is lost)

I was thinking to make the image target child of AR camera (to keeps is relative position to the camera) and put my image on top of it (a sample cube for now).
This will give me the correct positional result (image is not moving) but there are some rendering issues. (when I run it, it's blinking as I guess could be some rendering issues)

any comments and suggestions would be really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

The way vuforia works is that the camera is manipulated so that it has the same relative position to the target as your device has to the physical target in the real world.* Making one the child of the other won't allow this to happen. The whole point is to replace the "marker" with the 3D object so that it looks like it actually exists in the real world, moving and keeping itself fixed in place as the user moves their device around.

If you want something to be displayed on screen relative *to the screen* you should have it check to see if the target is detected and enabled, and depending on that state, enable or disable itself.  This object can then be a child of the camera (so it doesn't move).

*Alternatively it moves the *object* around relative to the camera.